# Webpack, images disappear after browser refresh, using webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've got a problem with my Webpack config. After  tag had been written, the image appears, but `devServer` remove all the pictures after styles applications right after page reload. And it wouldn't back until path was added again in  tag. [See this screenshot video to have a better image of what is happening](https://youtu.be/9JxnSNDZNrk).

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

let mode = 'development'
let target = 'web'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  mode = 'production'
  target = 'browserslist'
}

const plugins = [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './index.html',
  }),
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
  }),
]

module.exports = {
  mode,
  plugins,
  target,
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: {
    main: './main.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
    clean: true,
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3001,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: ['html-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|ico)$/i,
        type: mode === 'production' ? 'asset' : 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Bryce said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72732986/15288641) having `clean:false` inside `output` entry of `webpack.config.js` solves the issue (no need for the path to be null though). But it rises another one, a `dist` folder crowded with hashed CSS and JavaScript files. What I did is to set it only for development mode, like so:

```js
output: {
  // ...
  clean: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ,
},
```

And added an environment variable only for build in my `package.json`, like so:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue - I noticed that changing `output.clean` = `false` in the `webpack.dev.js` file resolve the issue when output.path was null.

The answer selected above worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in `html-webpack-plugin`. It was fixed in `v5.5.4` (https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/pull/1811).

**Update** the `html-webpack-plugin` to version `"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.4"` or newer (`5.6.0` is the latest version at the time of writing this answer). The following config will work in both dev or production mode:

```js
// ...
output: {
  clean: true
}
```